# How to find the angle from the center of a rectangle to its vertices

Tags: javascript, rectangles

I'm developing a collision detection system in Javascript, and I need to find from which side of the rectangle a ball collided.

Anyway, what I need right now is to find the angle from the center of a rectangle to its vertices. Like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image, I want to find that angle, but also the rest of the angles to the bottom left and top left vertices.

I know this is math, but I need to code the formula in Javascript anyway.

Let's say I have this:

```
var box = {
   width : 200,
   height : 100
};

var boxCenter = {x : box.width / 2, y : box.height / 2 };

var angleRight = // ... ;
var angleBottom = // ... ;
```

And so on

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: I needed to know the Formula, so I could implement it on Javascript, as you can see, the Math.atan() gave me what I wanted, I don't think all mathematicians know about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle (red) may be calculated with:

```
var angle = 2* Math.atan(height/width);
```

Comment: Good sir, thanks for your answer, if I updated my question to find another kind of angle, would you help me? I need to find the angle of the vertex but from the degree 0 (zero)

Comment: It's given in radians. If you want it in degrees you've gotta convert it.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I got a bit confused but now I got it sorted... Your answer gives me what I needed! 90 Degrees for a perfect square (: that was my test, and it's working